# JS объявление функций или основная функция JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, я новичок в JS. Решил заглянуть в исходники jquery и возник вопрос буквально на первой функции:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

    [...]

    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);
```

А не понятна конструкция `( )(window)` что это?

Comment: `window` - это аргумент безымянной и самовызывающейся функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это так называемая самовызывающаяся анонимная функция, в которую передается аргумент. 
Используется в основном для изоляции куска кода от внешней среды, и недопущения засорения глобальной области видимости. Вызывается сразу после объявления.

Стоить заметить, что в приведенном примере есть потенциальная ошибка. Обычно рекомендуется перед началом объявления самовызывающейся функции ставить точку с запятой:

```
;(function(){ /* code */ })()
```

Это позволит избежать проблем при "склейке" в один файл нескольких модулей, к примеру, запустив этот код, вы получите не совсем ожидаемый результат:

```
// module 1
var myFunc = function (str) {
    alert(str);
}

// Module 2
(function () {
    return 'blablabla';
}());
```

Comment: а в каких ситуациях она необходима? то есть `alert()` в коде и `(function() {alert();}());` дадут вызов